# firewire video capture not working with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, camera, firewire, video-capture-card

I used to transfer video by firewire (a.k.a. ieee1394, or i-link) with Ubuntu 12.04.

Sometimes from the command line with dvgrab and sometimes with Kino.

I haven't been able to make it work on 14.04 yet.

Any help/suggestions are really welcomed!

dvgrab responds with: Error: no camera exists

Kino says on the status bar: WARNING: raw1394 kernel module not loaded or failure to read/write/dev/raw1394

I followed these suggestions which worked for me with Ubuntu 12.04:

```
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FireWire/DigitalVideo
   sudo apt-get install dvgrab kino
   sudo ln /dev/fw0 /dev/raw1394
   sudo chmod 664 /dev/raw1394
```

I don't see the raw1394 module loaded, but I see the firewire-ohci and firewire core. I read that that is expected since the firewire-... modules replaced the raw1394 module, but I don't know enough about this to be sure.

Here is some more info:

In Synaptic Package Manager, I can see these installed:
libavc1394-0 libraw1394-11 libdc1394-22

```
$ lsmod |grep firewire
firewire_ohci          40409  0 
firewire_core          68769  1 firewire_ohci
crc_itu_t              12707  1 firewire_core
$ more /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-firewire.conf
# Select the legacy firewire stack over the new CONFIG_FIREWIRE one.
blacklist ohci1394
blacklist sbp2
blacklist dv1394
blacklist raw1394
blacklist video1394
#blacklist firewire-ohci
#blacklist firewire-sbp2
$ lsmod |grep 1394
$
$ sudo modprobe raw1394
modprobe: FATAL: Module raw1394 not found.
```

I then edited the blacklist-firewire.conf file to comment out ohci1394 and raw1394, and also edited /dev/modules adding ohci1394 and raw1394 at the end of the file in individual lines. Then rebooted. But this didn't help. One thing I notice is that the /dev/raw1394 had disappeared, so I recreated it and tried dvgrab and kino again with no luck.

To finish, I re-edited the two files to restore the version before my edits.

Again, any suggestion/comment/thoughts are very welcomed!

---

Today 4/2/2015, I kept trying a few things but I cannot make it work yet.

Here is what I tried:

Commented out all lines in /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-firewire.conf

Edited /etc/modules adding a line with: ohci1394, and  a line with: raw1394

From Synaptic, reinstalled libraw1394-11 and installed libraw1394-11-dbg libraw1394-doc libraw1394-dev libraw1394-tools

Rebooted

```
$sudo ln /dev/fw0 /dev/raw1394 (because it went away after reboot)
$sudo chmod 664 /dev/raw1394
```

Tried kino and dvgrab, but I got the same errors.

From Synaptic, searched for: 1394, and installed all that were not already installed except libconvert-ytext-perl: libavc1394-tools libavc1394-dev  libdc1394-22-doc libdc1394-utils libdc1394-22-dbg libdc1394-22-dev coriander libiec61883-dev dvsource

Rebooted

```
$sudo ln /dev/fw0 /dev/raw1394 (because it went away after reboot ... again)
$sudo chmod 664 /dev/raw1394
```

Tried kino and dvgrab, but I got the same errors.

```
$sudo lsmod |grep 1394
$
$sudo modprobe raw1394
modprobe: FATAL: Module raw1394 not found.
$dvgrab
Error: no camera exists
```

Opening Kino and selecting Capture still brings this message:
  WARNING: raw1394 kernel module not loaded or failure to read/write /dev/raw1394!

Comment: Does your camera show up if you run `plugreport` ?  If it's in there you should be able to tell dvgrab exactly what 1394 channel to find the camera on...  If not, then you may be running into a problem I've experienced in that some 1394 chips are not fully functional with Ubuntu, I forgot how it was that I identified the difference, but I've done a lot of DV capture on many machines, and some DV PCI cards ( or onboard I assume ) just don't fully work on Ubuntu.

Comment: Looks like you missed the output?

Comment: plugreport does not show the camera. After Node 0 GUID and a long hex number, it says: libiec61883 error: error reading oMPR, and libiec61883 error: error reading iMPR. I think you are probably right about being a hardware issue. I got the same result (didn't work) with two ExpressCards, one brand: SIIG, and another from: Century Accessory. But, the firewire camera connection worked with a much older PCI card on a desktop (I don't have that desktop anymore), and it's working well now with another laptop that I borrowed: Lenovo ThinkPad T61, which has an integrated firewire port.

Comment: yea, I always get the libiec61883 errors even when everything is working, but the oMPR and iMPR errors might be a sign of hardware issues.  Figuring out which cards will work is kinda like a witch hunt!  Not many add on cards tell you what kind of chips they use, and it turns out there are multiple different chips for firewire controllers. We've pretty much standardized on this Rosewill RC-504 - PCIe FireWire 1394a Card ... Doesn't really help a laptop user, but ¯\_(ツ)_/¯